# Javascript Eval Binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, eval

```
var data = $.grep(list, function (item, index) {
  return eval(paramBuilder);
});
```

This code statement is working in my local, when I deploy to the server, it gives this error.

> VM11410:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined
>           at eval (eval at  (application?v=c1cfyuXKgZC7JWR4mYcqCA8SX3ZBMMTjNBykdPM3mQ41:1), :1:1)

If I change the statement to this it workings successfully.

```
var data = $.grep(list, function (item, index) {
  console.log(item);
  return eval(paramBuilder);
});
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: This is an X/Y question. `eval()` is never a workable solution. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i am trying to generate dynamic condition. for example var x="a=1&&b=2" return x in grep

Comment: where does this condition come from? Why can't you just pass some filter function instead of that string?

Comment: Because "paramBuilder" is generated dynamically,i have to use  string condition in grep.

Comment: If it is generated and not passed from the client you can build it with functions, and get rid of that nasty `eval`

Comment: I tried it with `list = [1, 2, 3]` and `paramBuilder = 'item == 2'`, and the first code worked fine, returning `[2]`. If adding the `console.log()` fixes it, it looks like a bug in the JS optimizer.

Comment: Thansk Barmar, i think like you. But interesting thing, this code works in local browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
 IsHaveObject: function (list, object, properties) {
    if (Validator.IsValidObject(list)) {
        var paramBuilder = "";
        $.each(properties, function (index, item) {
            var value = "";
            if (object[item] === null)
                value = null;
            else if (typeof (object[item]) === 'number')
                value = object[item];
            else if (typeof (object[item]) === 'string')
                value = "'" + object[item] + "'";
            paramBuilder = paramBuilder + "forBug." + item + "===" + value + "&&";
        });
        paramBuilder = paramBuilder.substr(0, paramBuilder.length - 2);
        var data = $.grep(list, function (item, index) {
            var forBug = item;
            return eval(paramBuilder);
        });
        return data.length > 0 ? true : false;
    } else
        return true;
},
```

I added var forBug=item like console.log and unfortunately worked.